# String to int array in class constructor and call from main (C++)

Tags: c++, class

I'm barely beggining my C++ lessons, and I've been asked to create a class which will receive long integers, turn them into an array, adding two of these arrays, then turn the result back to a string and call it from the main. All of this must be done using pointers.

So far I've been unable to turn the first integer into an array and print it in the main.

This is the BigInteger class:

```
#define BIGINTEGER_H

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

class BigInteger {
  protected:
    string aString, bString, rNum;
  public:
    BigInteger(string aStr) {
      int* aNum = new int[sizeof(aStr)];
      for (int i = 0; i < aStr.length(); i++){
        aNum[i] = aStr[i];
      } 
    }

};

#endif
```

And this is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "biginteger.h"

int main() {
  BigInteger a("2147483647");

  cout << aNum;

  return 0;
}
```

Now, I know I should probably set a method that returns aNum, but I haven't find a way to do it.

I apologize if its a simple question and if my approach is kind of dumb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regardless of what your class teaches you, keep in mind C++ is all about things like `std::vector` to help manage array memory for you.

Comment: `new int[sizeof(aStr)]` and `for (int i = 0; i < aStr.length();` - don't you see the inconsistency?

Comment: you need a class method , say MakeString(), you cannot access anum from outside that class

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` isn't a useful value. Maybe you mean `str.length()`?

Comment: sizeof(astr) doesnt do what you think

Comment: if you dont know how to make a method you really need to go back and reread yr c++ intro, you managed to make the constructor, method is the same, just it has a return type

Comment: also the problem definition isnt clear, what does it mean to 'add 2 of these arrays,'

Comment: @S.M. It was `new int[aStr.length()]` You are right.

Comment: @pm100 Add 2 of these arrays as in I have to construct two variables of the type BigInteger in the main and add them using the methods I'm not implementing as of yet due to my inability to create the first object :(

Comment: @tadman Done. The only error I'm getting says aNum has not been declared. I thought I declare it in the constructor every time I create a new BigInteger object?

Comment: You declare it, allocate it, and then it falls out of scope and gets lost into the void creating a memory leak. You should either return the value you create, or use a `std::vector` to return it. The way you've coded this, `aNum` is a *local variable* and absolutely does not exist outside that scope.

Comment: So what you need is either an `int*` property you can access, or a method to get that value, like `const int* getArray() const` as an accessor.